# How can I remove the border of \fbox?

Tags: minipage, border, fbox

I don't want to change the colors, I want to remove.

Part of my code:

```
\fboxsep=0pt
\noindent\fbox{%

\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \scalefont{1.1}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{png/assinatura}\\[-25pt]
        \rule{9cm}{1pt}\\[5pt]
        Prof. Dr. Another Example\\
        Coordenador do University
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill%
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \scalefont{1.1}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{png/assinatura_mateus.png}\\[-56pt]
        \rule{9cm}{1pt}\\[5pt]
        Prof. Dr. Example\\
        Professor na University  \\
\end{minipage}}%
```

What I have:

[image]

Or, there is another way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\fbox` is `f`ramed `box`: it's sole purpose is to add a frame around something.  It looks to me that your code should work fine if you remove them (and the blank line after the first one).

Comment: Have you tried removing the `\fbox` completely? It seems that you don't want them... (or substitute with an `\mbox`)...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik and @Rmano, thanks for the suggestions! But when I remove `\fbox`,  the images and signatures goes one under another, instead of side by side. But `\mbox` solve this problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RxT minipages are positioned exactly like letters, they come side by side by default if they fit on the line. Probably you had a blank line in between, which puts them in different paragraphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside `minipage` you not need any boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \large
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=24mm,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\[-12mm] %{png/assinatura}
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\\[8mm]
    Prof. Dr. Another Example\\
    Coordenador do University
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \large
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=24mm,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\ [-12mm] %{png/assinatura_mateus.png}
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\\[8mm]
    Prof. Dr. Example\\
    Professor na University  \\
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I think the `%`  should go after the `\end{minipage} `  above the `\hfill` (where it has no effect)

Comment: Thanks alot! Now everything is working fine!

Comment: @Rmano, presence or absence of % after end of `minipage` or `\hfill` is due to size of space between `minipage`'s not so important. So in this particular case is after `\hfill` superfluous.

Comment: @RxT, you are welcome!

Comment: @Zarko yes, in this case, it doesn't matter --- you have a space after the first minipage + an infinity stretchable space. It would matter if you try to make the two minipages equal to exactly half the size of the line.